# running more than 8 threads in quad core processor

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, threadpool, cpu-usage

I had a threadpool with 10 threads and a lot of text data to process , i am running those threads in parallel and i am unable to utilise full cpu resorce of core i7 vPro processor, somebody help me on this. I want maximum cpu utilization.

Comment: A little bit of code would be helpful to answer the question.

Comment: Why why why??? A 100 line word text file does NOT need 8 threads to process. You're wasting resources and doing silly things. STAHP

Comment: the 100 sentences are translated into 6 different languages and a word count operation is performed on the text

Comment: I wrote and ran a 20 thread process on a Windows Intel two core workstation, and the best I could get was 50% utilization of the two cores.  Your operating system, as well as the JRE, determines how threads are processed.

Comment: @DunAnt How are you actually translating the sentences? If you're feeding them into an external service like Google Translate, there is *no point whatsoever* in multithreading your application. The overhead incurred by network communication is *orders of magnitude* larger than the actual computing time required. Even if it's your own translation engine, local dictionary lookups are likely to be so expensive that I/O can't feed 8 threads.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases instead of doing the same thing in each thread doing separate jobs and using synchronized queues to communicate gives better results. Try to split the application so that all read operations are done from a single thread, then the data is supplied to worker threads for processing, and another thread does post-processing (if there is any). You may find such model using much more processing power and doing the work significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly likely you have more overhead than CPU utilisation.

- This can be because it takes time to read the file and break it into sentences. As you don't see 100% CPU, this is my guess.
- The overhead of starting and adding tasks to other threads is greater the amount of work each task does.  You would expect to see close to 100% CPU utilisation but far less speed up than you expect. It could even be slower than using one thread.

Unless your JVM is warmed up, you may find this makes more difference than using multiple threads. (A 100 sentence files will not be near enough)

Comment: I even hav a 500 sentence file and same is the case with that too, the entire process involves translating the text into 6  different languages

Comment: In that case I would translate one language per thread, with one thread doing the reading into sentences. That should be CPU intensive enough. I assume you are doing the translation in Java and not using any external resource or service.

Answer (score 1):

If each thread is supposed to also read the sentence from the file in addition to processing it, then I suspect the disk is a bottleneck in this situation. Parallel reads from a single disk usually result in performance degradation with respect to a single sequential read.

In my opinion you should either leave everything to a single thread, or at least serialize the reading and parallelize only the sentence processing using a single producer-multiple consumer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading comes with some overhead from subdividing the task in jobs, feeding the jobs to a jobqueue, then letting a `ThreadPoolExecutor` execute the jobs, maybe combining the results when finished. Even if there is no contention due to disk access or other shared ressources, I found that subdividing jobs to become smaller than 1ms is not worth the overhead. When running on  large machines with multiple sockets, that threshold is even higher due to the increased cache coherency overhead.